# Combining AND and OR bitwise operators

Tags: c, math, binary

To safely adjust bits within a register I use:

```
DDRA  |= 0b01100000;
DDRA  &= 0b01111111;
```

- The first line will set the 5th and 6th bits TRUE, regardless of their current states and will not affect the other bits
- The second line will set the 7th bit FALSE, regardless of its current state without affecting other bits

How could these two operations be simplified?

Comment: Why do you believe this is not the simplest possible code to do this?

Comment: If you would prefer to set all the data direction bits 5,6,7 in a single write, then you can use `DDRA = (DDRA & 0b00011111) | 0b01100000;`

Comment: @EOF As there may be a simpler way to write this that I do not know of

Comment: You can’t simplify them more.

Comment: @Luc There is no (substantially) better way of writing this in c. On some processor architectures, there are ternary vector logical operations (ARM has `vbsl` and friends, x86-64 AVX512 has `vpternlog`), which can do this in a single processor instruction, but only on vector registers. Also, on any reasonably modern processor the c-version will be fast, provided the compiler is at least minimally competent.

Answer (score 1):

```
DDRA = (DDRA << 1) >> 1;
```

The above one might be faster than.

```
DDRA &= 0b01111111;
```

Depending on if it's an 8bit hardware-register (or an 8bit subregister of a 16bit hardware-register), DDRA has an unsigned datatype and the overflow-flag and carry-over-flag of your CPU cause no problems.